# Is it possible, in sourecode, to create a complete theme palette based on a primary color like the theme builder does?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Since the title attempts to address every part of my question, which is very difficult, I need to clearify a bit:

I want to be able to apply a theme to my Office UI Fabric application with all the different color shades an Office UI Fabric theme should have, without having to define each shade myself. The only things I want to define are the primary theme color, the body text color and the body background color. This is just what the [theme generator on the Office UI Fabric website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/customizations/colors) does.

So to get to the point: Is it possible to use the functionality of the theme generator in any Office UI Fabric application?

My naive approach was to use `createTheme`, since it accepts a partial theme, and I hoped to get a full one back:

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: { themePrimary: '#007610' },
  semanticColors: { bodyBackground: '#ffffff', bodyText: '#000000' },
});
loadTheme(theme);
```

Alas, this wasn't the case. Only the properties provided are applied.

So is there a simple (official) way to do this or are the sources of the theme creator available somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some investigation of the `ColorPage.tsx` from the Office UI Fabric repository I found the missing pieces to achieve this myself. The code below is just a very simple usage of that mechanism, that suffices my needs. For now, I don't want the user to change the main background or foreground colors, hence the simplifications. Use and extend it at your own risk, but feel free to ask me, if something isn't clear. But I guess its rather clear what's going on here.

```js
import { loadTheme } from '@uifabric/styling';
import {
  IThemeRules,
  ThemeGenerator,
  themeRulesStandardCreator,
} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/ThemeGenerator';
import { getColorFromString } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/utilities/color/getColorFromString';
import { IColor } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/utilities/color/interfaces';

export default class ThemeProvider {
  private themeRules: IThemeRules;

  constructor() {
    const themeRules = themeRulesStandardCreator();
    ThemeGenerator.insureSlots(this.themeRules, false);
    ThemeGenerator.setSlot(themeRules.backgroundColor, getColorFromString('#ffffff'), false, true, true);
    ThemeGenerator.setSlot(themeRules.foregroundColor, getColorFromString('#000000'), false, true, true);
    this.themeRules = themeRules;
  }

  public loadThemeForColor(hexColor: string): void {
    const newColor: IColor = getColorFromString(hexColor);

    const themeRules = this.themeRules;
    ThemeGenerator.setSlot(themeRules.primaryColor, newColor.str, false, true, true);
    this.themeRules = themeRules;
    const theme = ThemeGenerator.getThemeAsJson(this.themeRules);
    loadTheme({
      ...{ palette: theme },
      isInverted: false,
    });
  }
}
```

For more insights have a look at the `ColorPage.tsx` yourself within the official repo, since I didn't strive to understand everything going on in there.